# I am not able to click radiobuttons using Robot Framework.(and selenium2Library)

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, radio-button, robotframework

Could anyone help me out please?

Actually, the **radiobuttons are always in the DOM** but they are visible on the page based on *ADDRESS* field, so as you can see below if *Pickup* and *Delivery* timezone are same then the radiobuttons are not visible on page: 
[image: here]

but if they(pickup and delivery timezone) are different then the *RADIO BUTTONS*  are visible as shown below:
 [image: here].

Now in my script I try to set all the radiobuttons as NO, so when I run it the script passes but in real the radiobuttons are left untouched. The result is PASS as shown below
[image: here]

and Chrome browser after the script run is shown below:
[image: here]

Here is the script I wrote for waiting and clicking on radiobuttons:

```
`wait until element is enabled  id=exportclearance_1
  page should contain radio button  id=exportclearance_1
  click element  id=exportclearance_1
  click element  id=transitclearance_1
  click element  id=importclearance_1
  click element  id=insurance_1`
```

Here is the HTML of page:

```
`<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="">
<div class="col-sm-6">
<input id="exportclearance_0" name="export_clearance" value="True" autocomplete="off" type="radio"/>
<label class="control-label control-label-light clearance" for="exportclearance_0">Yes</label>
<input id="exportclearance_1" name="export_clearance" value="False" autocomplete="off" type="radio"/>
<label class="control-label control-label-light clearance" for="exportclearance_1">No</label>
<br/>
</div>
</div>
<div id="exportclearance-textarea" style="display:none">
<div class="row col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-4">
<textarea id="field-exportclearance" class="form-control customs-field" cols="40" name="export_clearance_instructions" placeholder="Instructions for export clearance (E.g. Broker details, Customs number, etc.)" rows="2"/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div id="transitclearance-textarea" style="display:none">
<div class="form-group">
<div id="importclearance-textarea" style="display:none">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div id="id_attachment_formset_parent">
<div class="form-group">
<di
```

`

Comment: You can try clicking on label yes/no. It may works.

Comment: as in? I am already clicking on the element by their id's as written in code, so `id=exportclearance_1` means I try to click on NO for export clearance radiobutton. @Murthi

Comment: you are clicking on input tag but I am asking to try with label tag.

Comment: What does "not able to click" mean? It appears you are indeed able to click them since your script isn't throwing any errors. Have you tried using the [Select Radio Button](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Select%20Radio%20Button) keyword?

Comment: yes, I did try `select radio button  export_clearance  True` but that also did not work. "Not able to click" means that although script is not throwing any errors it is not clicking on the mentioned radiobuttons (though I am not sure why). Might be that script is too fast or something but I tried sleep and wait for element as well, but no luck as such. @BryanOakley

Comment: I tried with xpath as well as few other methods `//div[(@class='col-sm-6')]//input[contains(@name, 'export_clearance') and contains(@value, 'False')]` but still no luck. @Murthi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript executor worked for me as given below.

`execute javascript  document.getElementById('insurance_1').click()`